# How do i share data across devices using bluetooth in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, bluetooth

I am trying to share data across devices using bluetooth plugin, but nothing has worked so far. I am not getting nearby devices by scanning from any plugin.

The plugins which i have used so far:

1. flutter_bluetooth_basic
2. flutter_bluetooth_advanced
3. bluetooth
4. flutter_scan_bluetooth
5. flutter_bluetooh_serial
6. bluetooth_manager
7. flutter_bluetooth_custom
8. quick_blue
9. flutter_nearby_connection
10. bluetooth_connector
11. flutter_reactive_ble
12. bluetooth_low_energy
13. flutter_blue
14. flutter_blue_plus
15. flutter_blue_elves
16. flutter_blue_plugin
17. flutter_bluetooth_plus
18. flutter_ttc_blue
19. ble_reader
20. ble_sdk
21. flutter_blue_pro

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: That is quite unfortunate! Do you have any more information on why specific plugins did not work? Since you've tagged Android and iOS you need to know that Bluetooth Classic (also called Bluetooth Serial) won't work in that case, you would need Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) to send between Android and iOS. But BLE works differently from Bluetooth Classic, one phone needs to advertise it's presence to be found. Please use a generic BLE scanner such as [nRF COnnect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile) to scan for nearby devices first.

Comment: Also there are many questions on StackOverflow regarding flutter_reactive_ble and it seems to work for others. Maybe there are simply no BLE devices near you, but I would be especially interested in any error messages you get using this plugin